# Failed to load viewstate - dynamic controls in ASP.NET using nested GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my project I am working on showing Task Group and Task (i.e. Parent-child) in one screen with the ability to Add/Edit/Delete the parent (Task Group) record and also to Add/Edit/Delete associated Task. For this I am using nested `Grid View` (parent-child).

I am implementing the sample application mentioned in the below link to my `ASP.NET` web based project.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One

my `.ASPX` looks as mentioned below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Unicorn.Master" CodeBehind="TaskAndTaskGroup.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vipassi.Web.TaskGroup.TaskAndTaskGroup"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
        var div = document.getElementById(obj);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "block";
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "../../Resources/images/minus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "../../Resources/images/minus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Close to view other TaskGroups";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "../../Resources/images/plus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "../../Resources/images/plus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Expand to show Tasks";
        }
    }
</script>


<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#f1f1f1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="task_group_id"
        ShowFooter="true" Font-Size="Small"
        Font-Names="Verdana" runat="server" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"  BorderStyle=Outset 
        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted"
        OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" AllowSorting="true">
        <RowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0083C1" ForeColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("task_group_id") %>', 'one');">
                        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("task_group_id") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Tasks for TaskGroup <%# Eval("task_group_id") %>" width="9px" border="0" src="../../Resources/images/plus.gif" />
                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TaskGroup ID" SortExpression="task_group_id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTaskGroupID" Text='<%# Eval("task_group_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTaskGroupID" Text='<%# Eval("task_group_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskGroupID" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Group" SortExpression="task_group">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("task_group") %></ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskGroup" Text='<%# Eval("task_group") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskGroup" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fiscal Year" SortExpression="Fiscal_Year">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Fiscal_Year") %></ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFiscalYear" Text='<%# Eval("Fiscal_Year") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFiscalYear" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active" SortExpression="Active_Flag">
                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Active_Flag")%></ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActiveFlag" Text='<%# Eval("Active_Flag") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActiveFlag" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteTaskGroup" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddTaskGroup" CommandName="AddTaskGroup" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%">
                            <div id="div<%# Eval("task_group_id") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto; width: 97%">
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" BackColor="White" Width="100%" Font-Size="X-Small"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Verdana" runat="server" DataKeyNames="task_group_id" ShowFooter="true"
                                    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating"
                                    OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" GridLines="None"
                                    OnRowUpdated="GridView2_RowUpdated" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_CancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound"
                                    OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GridView2_RowDeleted" OnSorting="GridView2_Sorting"
                                    BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="#0083C1">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0083C1" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task ID" SortExpression="task_id">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTaskID" Text='<%# Eval("task_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTaskID" Text='<%# Eval("task_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="task_name">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("task_name")%></ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTask" Text='<%# Eval("task_name")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTask" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fiscal Year" SortExpression="fiscal_year">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("fiscal_year")%></ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskFiscalYear" Text='<%# Eval("fiscal_year")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskFiscalYear" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active" SortExpression="Active_Flag">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Active_Flag")%></ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskActiveFlag" Text='<%# Eval("Active_Flag")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskActiveFlag" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteTaskGroup" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddTask" CommandName="AddTask" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource SortParameterName="sortExpression" EnablePaging="true" ID="ObjectDataSource1"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRecords" TypeName="Vipassi.BLL.Classes.TaskGroup.TaskGroupBLL"
        SelectMethod="ListforTaskGroup" SelectCountMethod="ListCountforTaskGroup" StartRowIndexParameterName="startIndex"
        runat="server">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="orgId" Name="orgId" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

You can disable the VIEWSTATE of ASPX page /User Control  :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/TaskAndTaskGroup.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vipassi.Web.TaskGroup.TaskAndTaskGroup"  EnableViewState="false"%>
```

Option 2:

You can also change your source code to make sure the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Hope this will help you.